# CGAffineTransform disfigure UIBarButton after a few rotation

Tags: ios, swift

Has anyone seen a situation when trying to animate a symmetrically shaped UIBarButton with CGAffineTransform rotation for a few times, then ended up with the button out of shape???

```
optionButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if this button has any autoresizing masks or autolayout constraints added?

Comment: @Giraffe, check the contentMode of the `UIImageView` of this button. Try setting it to .scaleAspectFit

Comment: @user3581248 my custom UIButton was added to the customView layer of the UINavigationBar, so I don't feel like it was caused by using the wrong constraints.

Comment: @KrishnaCA How do I change the contentMode of a background image of the UIButton????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by resetting the UIButton's identity matrix to identity, it seems to fix the problem. But why though???

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.20, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: { 
            if let optionsButton = self.homeController?.optionsButton {
                optionsButton.transform = optionsButton.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
            }
        }) { (finished: Bool) in
            if let optionsButton = self.homeController?.optionsButton {
                optionsButton.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }
}
```

Ok so the correct & short answer is that I forgot to define the "contentMode" of backgroundImage of my UIButton.

```
button.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Please correct me if I am wrong. The long answer:

The identity matrix layer referenced to the UIView layer of the UIButton is not in a square shape (it maybe very difficult to spot the difference in shape if they are only a few pixels' difference. Looking into Xcode's UI Debug tool could help.) When the button animates itself, the longer side swaps places with the shorter side in the identity matrix layer (not UIView). As a result, if I keep tapping this UIButton for animation, both side of the "rectangle" will grow longer and then ultimately become stretched. Reseting the UIButton's identity matrix solves the problem by chance because the matrix layer got reset back to its original position, but it is just a hacky solution.